# Cannot use object of type DOMNamedNodeMap as array error in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am using following code to parse XML:

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array(
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->attributes['url']->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

It works perfectly on localhost without any errors. On the server, however, I get `Cannot use object of type DOMNamedNodeMap as array` error for the middle line which stores `desc`. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->attributes['url']->nodeValue
```

You're fetching an element node with:

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)...
```

Element nodes have an attributes property, that is an instance of `DOMNamedNodeList`. This is not an array and does not implement `ArrayAccess`. So you can not access the attribute nodes using array syntax. You will have to use the method `DOMNamedNodeList::getNamedItem()`.

```
$node
  ->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')
  ->item(0)
  ->attributes
  ->getNamedItem('url')...
```

This will return the attribute node, so you can access its value with `DOMAttribute::$value`.

```
$node
  ->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')
  ->item(0)
  ->attributes
  ->getNamedItem('url')
  ->value
```

However you can fetch the attribute value directly from the element node using `DOMElement::getAttribute()`.

```
$node
  ->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')
  ->item(0)
  ->getAttribute('url')
```

An even better way is to use XPath. `DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows you to use expression to fetch nodes and scalar values from an DOM.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->loadXml($rssFeedXml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($rss);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $itemNode) {
  $feed[] = [
    'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $itemNode),
    'desc' => $xpath->evaluate('string(enclosure/@url)', $itemNode),
    'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $itemNode)
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThW It was explained in great detail.

Answer (score -1):

You could try explicitly casting the nodelist as an array to see if that resolves things - totally untested btw.

```
<?php
    $items=$rss->getElementsByTagName('item');
    if( is_object( $items ) ){

        $col=(array)$items;
        if( !is_array( $col ) ) exit('Not an array!');

        foreach ( $col as $node ) {
            $item = array(
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc'  => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->attributes['url']->nodeValue,
                'link'  => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
            );

            array_push( $feed, $item );
        }
    } else {
        exit( 'Type: '.gettype( $items ) );
    }
?>
```

Comment: It does not output anything in this case. The screen is blank.